# Simple key binding issue

Tags: key-bindings, atom-editor

So I finally got to try out atom with one of the unofficial windows builds. Now I'm trying to create a simple binding (and then get my feet wet with real plugins).

The binding is simple, when you are in the vim plugin command mode and press ':', open up the command palette.

I started off with this as my binding:

```
'.editor':
  ':': 'command-palette:toggle'
```

This works fine, but I only want this in command mode. If I change the selector to be:

```
'.command-mode':
  ':': 'command-palette:toggle'
```

This doesn't work, even though the command-mode class is on the same element as the editor class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried combining the two, like in CSS?

```
'.editor .command-mode':
  ':': 'command-palette:toggle'
```